# Create empty dataframes in loop of same size in r and give them colnames of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

"aa", "bb" and "cc" are the three empty data frames i have to create using loop and give them colname of df1.

```
df1=data.frame(name= c("x", "y", "m"),
       age=c(25,28,31),
       achivements= c(0,1,1))
```

**Code that I am trying to get **

```
stored_df_name= c("aa", "bb", "cc")
for(i in stored_df_name){
 i= data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)
 names(i) <- names(df1)
 }
```

But its not creating 3 data frames, but instead, creating data frame named i of dim(3,3)

Comment: You are overwriting the i within for loop. I think you would like to vectorize it without side effect like you might do with `purrr`. But in your code you may create a empty list before the for loop `mydfs <- list(); for(i in stored_df_name){ mydfs[i] <- df1[0,] }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This base R solution uses a `lapply` loop to create a list of data.frames, then assigns the list members' names from the names vector and, finally, puts the df's in the `.GlobalEnv`.

```
df_list <- lapply(stored_df_name, function(x){
  setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)), names(df1))
})
names(df_list) <- stored_df_name
list2env(df_list, envir = .GlobalEnv)
rm(df_list)

aa
#  name age achivements
#1   NA  NA          NA
#2   NA  NA          NA
#3   NA  NA          NA
```

If the data.frames need to empty, run the code above with `nrow=0` in the `matrix(.)` instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(name= c("x", "y", "m"),
               age=c(25,28,31),
               achivements= c(0,1,1))

stored_df_name= c("aa", "bb", "cc")

output <- vector("list", length = 3)

for(i in 1:length(stored_df_name)) {
  output[[i]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
  names(output[[i]]) <- names(df1)
}

output <- setNames(output, stored_df_name)

> rbindlist(output[1])
   name age achivements
1:   NA  NA          NA
2:   NA  NA          NA
3:   NA  NA          NA
```

Output is a list of length 3 and each component is a data frame. You can use `rbindlist` function from `data.table` package to turn each or all components into a single or row-bound data frames.

Answer (score 0):

With a `for` loop, and minimal changes from OP's attempt:

```
for(name in stored_df_name){
  empty_df = data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3))
  names(empty_df) <- names(df1)
  assign(name, empty_df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far, the Rui Barrada answer seems the most efficient to create the dfs

The way I did is more like a copy.

```r
df1=data.frame(name= c("x", "y", "m"),
               age=c(25,28,31),
               achivements= c(0,1,1))

stored_df_name= c("aa", "bb", "cc")

with_for_loop1 <- function(){
  
  mydfs <- list()
  for(i in stored_df_name){
    mydfs[[i]] <- df1[0,]
  }
  
  return(mydfs)
}

with_for_loop1()
#> $aa
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $bb
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $cc
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

with_for_loop2 <- function(){
  
  mydfs <- list()
  for(i in stored_df_name){
    mydfs[[i]] <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=3)), names(df1))
  }
  
  return(mydfs)
}

with_for_loop2()
#> $aa
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $bb
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $cc
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

with_for_loop3 <- function(){
  
  mydfs <- list()
  for(i in stored_df_name){
    mydfs[[i]] <- setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)), names(df1))
  }
  
  return(mydfs)
}

with_for_loop3()
#> $aa
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA
#> 
#> $bb
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA
#> 
#> $cc
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA

with_lapply1 <- function(){
  df_list <- lapply(stored_df_name, function(x){
    setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)), names(df1))
  })
  names(df_list) <- stored_df_name
  return(df_list)
}

with_lapply1()
#> $aa
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA
#> 
#> $bb
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA
#> 
#> $cc
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA

with_lapply2 <- function(){
  df_list <- lapply(stored_df_name, function(x){
    setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=3)), names(df1))
  })
  names(df_list) <- stored_df_name
  return(df_list)
}

with_lapply2()
#> $aa
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $bb
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $cc
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

with_lapply3 <- function(){
  df_list <- lapply(stored_df_name, function(x){df1[0,]})
  names(df_list) <- stored_df_name
  return(df_list)
}

with_lapply3()
#> $aa
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $bb
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> $cc
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)


with_purrr1 <- function() purrr::imap(stored_df_name, ~ df1[0,])
with_purrr1()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

with_purrr2 <- function() purrr::imap(stored_df_name, ~ setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=3)), names(df1)))
with_purrr2()
#> [[1]]
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] name        age         achivements
#> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

with_purrr3 <- function() purrr::imap(stored_df_name, ~ setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3)), names(df1)))
with_purrr3()
#> [[1]]
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   name age achivements
#> 1   NA  NA          NA
#> 2   NA  NA          NA
#> 3   NA  NA          NA

tictoc::tic()
benchr::benchmark(
  with_for_loop1 = with_for_loop1(),
  with_for_loop2 = with_for_loop2(),
  with_for_loop3 = with_for_loop3(),
  with_lapply1 = with_lapply3(),
  with_lapply2 = with_lapply2(),
  with_lapply3 = with_lapply1(),
  with_purrr1 = with_purrr1(), 
  with_purrr2 = with_purrr2(), 
  with_purrr3 = with_purrr3(), 
  times = 100000
) -> a
tictoc::toc()
#> 84.444 sec elapsed

a
#> Benchmark summary:
#> Time units : microseconds 
#>            expr n.eval   min lw.qu median  mean up.qu   max    total relative
#>  with_for_loop1  1e+05  69.7  82.8   88.6  93.8  96.0 39500  9380000     1.52
#>  with_for_loop2  1e+05  47.2  54.9   58.2  62.0  62.9 39900  6200000     1.00
#>  with_for_loop3  1e+05  46.9  54.8   58.3  61.7  63.1 43600  6170000     1.00
#>    with_lapply1  1e+05  70.2  85.1   91.4  97.2  98.4 53300  9720000     1.57
#>    with_lapply2  1e+05  48.1  57.2   61.2  64.6  66.2  4920  6460000     1.05
#>    with_lapply3  1e+05  48.0  57.1   61.2  64.4  66.3  5420  6440000     1.05
#>     with_purrr1  1e+05 110.0 138.0  146.0 153.0 154.0 43500 15300000     2.50
#>     with_purrr2  1e+05  87.2 108.0  117.0 121.0 126.0  5920 12100000     2.01
#>     with_purrr3  1e+05  85.8 108.0  117.0 121.0 126.0  6300 12100000     2.01

options(benchr.use_ggplot = TRUE)
boxplot(a) + ggplot2::theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>